# Fullcalendar: getting "Va.time is undefined" when trying to assign a moment to event.end

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar and it is working fine.
I allow users to drag events, but sometimes I need to force the event to start on a specific date. For example, some events MUST start on a Monday, so if a user drags it to a different weekday, I'll force the event move to the previous Monday.

So, on the eventDrop callback, I have something like:

```
jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({
...
...
  eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
    if (/*must force new event start date*/) {
      var duration = event.end.diff(event.start, 'd');
      event.start = moment('2015-07-01');
      event.end = moment('2015-07-01').add(duration, 'd');
    }
  }
})
```

Some explaining:

- I must calculate the original duration, because when I change the
  start date, Fullcalendar assumes the end date is the same and changes
  the event duration accordingly. So it forces me to assign a new end
  date (is there another way to do this?)
- assigning a new date to event.start works fine
- assigning a new date to event.end always returns:

> TypeError: Va.time is undefined

Am I missing something, or maybe overcomplicating things?
Is the error a bug?

Thanks in advance for helping me on this!

Comment: I had a similar problem, getting `ab.time is undefined`. I also figured out that my line `event.end = moment(event.start).add(2, 'hours');` led to this error. Changing the times of an event object with moment.js removes some important variables from the object! Before: `Object { _isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: true, _offset: 0, _pf: Object, _locale: Object, _d: Date 2016-05-06T00:00:00.000Z, _ambigTime: true, _ambigZone: true, _fullCalendar: true }` afterwards are missing: `_ambigTime: true, _ambigZone: true, _fullCalendar: true`.

Answer (score 1):

Just modify the existing `moment` like this:

```
eventDrop: function (event) {
    event.start.day(1); //Move the startdate to day 1 (Monday, 0 = Sunday)
    event.end.day(1); //Also move the enddate to Monday
}
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hhhyzj5p/2/)

I'm not sure what causes the error. It looks like it has to be something to do with setting a new momentjs object in either the `event.start` or `event.end`.

Comment: Many thanks for pointing me to the right direction.

Since I have to calculate the new start and end dates, I use a moment for such calculation and determine its dayOfYear().

Then I just update the dates with event.start.dayOfYear() and event.end.dayOfYear() and the problem is solved.

For some reason, momentjs does not have a simple method to update its date (something like moment.date('YYYY-MM-DD') )

Comment: @AlexandrePaulo I hope it fixes your problem, if you need more help let me know ;)